# Google Sheets API Multiple processes access to google sheet problem

Tags: node.js, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api

I have a google sheet and one program_A that can access to this sheet to get/update values.

The processes are:
1: access sheet and get current data -> 2: change data -> 3: update sheet.

The problem is if the sheet is changed (let's say another program B appended 1 more row to the sheet) after program A got the current data.
Then after that, the program A will not know about the new appended line and then it will update the data to the wrong row.

Get sheet data from A1 -> W

```
sheet_data = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
    spreadsheetId: account_Check.Sheet_Id,
    range: 'sheet!A1:W',
});
```

Update to A5. But the A5 was changed because another process appended 1 more row to A3 for example.

```
await sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
    spreadsheetId: account_Check.Sheet_Id,
    range: 'sheet!A5',
    valueInputOption: 'RAW',
    resource: {values: sheet_data_write},
});
```

Is there any way that process A can update to correct rows if other process B has changed the sheet before?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider the use of Lock Service.

Comment: @Cooper Thank you. This seems good. I will try it. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock

Comment: Hi Cooper, Lock Service works only under the scope of one Google app script. Because I am using an external Nodejs program then it does not work. But I referred to it and created my simple custom lock service.